# Cout from class method does nothing

Tags: c++, class, vector, methods, cout

I have a class "beaker" that represents a beaker with n-dices that have n-faces. It has a method "roll" which returns a vector with n-elements where each element represents a dice. Then I have another class "board" that for now, it only prints the values generated by beaker.roll using cout;

So I call the beaker.roll function to pass the result to print them, but it does nothing. I have no compile errors/IntelliSense warnings. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;


class beaker {
    public:
        int diceCount, diceFaces;
        
        beaker() {
            diceCount = 2;
            diceFaces = 6;
        };

        beaker(int count, int faces) {
            diceCount = count;
            diceFaces = faces;
        };

        //Dice values
        vector<uint8_t> dice;

        //METHODS

        //RETURN DICE i VALUE
        int diceValue(int d) {
            return dice.at(d-1);
        }
        //ROLL DICE + RETURN RESULT
        vector<uint8_t> roll() {
            std::mt19937 mt(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, diceFaces);
            for (int i=0; i<diceCount; i++) {
                dice.push_back(dist(mt));
            }
            return dice;
        }       

        //RETURN LAST DICE NUMBERS
        vector<uint8_t> result() {
            return dice;
        }
};

class board {
    public:
        void Print(vector<uint8_t> dice) {
            for (int i=0; i<dice.size(); i++) {
                cout << dice.at(i);
            }
        }
};

int main() {
    beaker beaker;
    board board;
    board.Print(beaker.roll());
}
```

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Still not working. It adds the newline but without printing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the values in `dice` are of type `uint8_t`, which the `cout::<<` operator is interpreting as `unsigned char`, so it is printing out the values as ASCII characters.  However, the values are between 1 and 6, and [ASCII characters less than 32](http://www.asciitable.com) are mostly non-printing characters, so they aren't visible in the output.

To convince the `cout::<<` operator to print the values as integers instead, update the code to this:

```
void Print(vector<uint8_t> dice) {
    for (int i=0; i<dice.size(); i++) {
        cout << static_cast<int>(dice.at(i));
    }
    cout << std::endl;  // just to make sure the buffer gets flushed ASAP
}
```

Comment: Recommending a c-style cast seems odd here. Any reason you preferred that to [static_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)? Also, if you're going to recommend casting, it's probably worth explaining what that is, or linking to a prior post to that effect.

Comment: Less typing?  Habit?  I'll change it.  :)

Comment: I kinda know what casting means, but never dared to use it. What's the best way to do it in c++? I would like some formed opinion about it. Not that I couldn't google it, but what would be the best on this case?